# Cannot add Email as a tab in Lex page

Tags: email, lightning-app-builder, tag

I'm new to salesforce, so this might be a simple question, but I looked a lot for a solution and could not find one at all.

I'm trying to add `Email` as a tab on the LEX page side bar as can be seen in this image:

[image: tab area]

but that option doesn't appear.

I made sure that `Email` is included in the `Mobile and Lightning Experience Action` - in Page Layouts, but as an option to add to the tabs in the app builder, it doesn't seem to appear.

Is there a correct way to do it? Or does anyone know of a work-around way of doing it?

I'd appreciate any opinion which would get me closer to the solution.

Comment: I think this sounds correct based on [Spring'23](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_productivity_activity_composer.htm&release=242&type=5). If you really want to go back to tabbed it seems that you can based on the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.activity_composer_return_to_tabbed.htm&type=5).

Comment: Re-reading your post, I realize that my above answer might not be correctly addressing your issue - can you please clarify what it is you are asking about?

In the screenshot you shared from the Lightning App Builder, the component is there (but just with a different layout option). Was that your question?

Or are you saying that when you view a record using this page layout, the activities component isn't visible on the record?

Or are you saying that you are not seeing the Activities component in the Lightning App Builder?

Answer (score 1):

The component (called Activities) is already on your page as Jerry says, but if you want to change the way it looks you can do that with a simple check of a checkbox:
[image: Activity timeline]

I was **not** a fan of this new UI, so VERY relieved to find the checkbox ;) When you check it, it looks like this on the page:

[image: tabbed activity view]

Answer (score 0):

I looked in my org and noticed the same thing. I also noticed the envelope icon, shown below, which does bring up a window to write a new email. I see it in your screenshot too, in a slightly different spot due to where it's placed on your page layout.

I haven't yet found any documentation on this, but I assume it was a change in Winter '24.

[image: Activity Component with envelope icon called out]

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading your post, I realize that my above answer might not be correctly addressing your issue.
In the screenshot you shared from the Lightning App Builder, the component is there (but just with a different layout option).  Was that your question?

Or are you saying that when you view a record using this page layout, the activities component isn't visible on the record?

Or are you saying that you are not seeing the Activities component in the Lightning App Builder?
[image: Component list]

Comment: This seems more appropriate as a comment rather than an answer (as I don't think it answers the question).

Comment: I agree that it doesn't answer the question @DerekF, but I chose to add it as an answer since you can't include a picture in a comment, nor is it possible to format for easier reading.  what would you suggest here?  comment or "answer"?

Comment: OK, so you just need to enable the "Use tabbed activity view" which I shared in my initial answer - hope that solves it!

Comment: no it doesn't answer my question.
I know I can change the display option,
what I was wondering was - why isn't there an option to add email as its own tab near - activities, chatter etc.
It should have bein able to be put there, because it's one of the fields added to the Mobile and Lightning Experience section on page layouts
so how come it isn't an option?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but the image is useful as Lara says so for now I've made it a community wiki - not really the right fit but better than deleting IMO. Hopefully we can evolve from here. Lara if a proper answer is found do please post it as a new one so you don't miss out on rep!